# HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено. Сервер не видит ресурс, который нужно загружать. При запросе на /hello_world получаю 404

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Класс

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<h1> Hello world! </h1>");
        pw.println("</html>");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

файл web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello_world</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено
Type Status Report

Message Not found

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Comment: Попробуй зайти в Edit configuration твоего Tomcat -> Deployment -> свойство Applicaction Context поставь "/". Если не сработает, то попробуй еще зайти в Project Structure -> Modules -> Web -> Там у тебя будет Type и Path. Проверь, правильно ли Path указывает на твой файл с web.xml. И еще ниже в свойстве Path Relative to Deployment Root тоже поставь значение "/"

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!